# Multiple Shell command in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to get the version of my compilation from a text file. I'm using this command

```
grep -w -m 1 "V1" server.h | sed $(VERSION) 's/#define V1[\t]//'
```

It works fine but now I'm trying to execute it from my Makefile using shell:

```
VERSION=$(shell grep -w -m 1 "V1" server.h | sed $(VERSION) 's/#define V1[\t]//')
```

but I'm not able to make it works because of the `|`. If I only put one command, grep for example it runs fine, there's another way to indicate the `|` to concatenate expressions? Or how else can I do this?

**Edit:**

Hi, thanks for the answer,

Reading your answer i realize that copy/paste has betrayed me jeje, this is the right expression i'm using:

VERSION:=$(shell grep -w -m 1 "V2" server.h | sed 's/#define V2[\t]//')

And this is the output of Makefile:

- unterminated call to function shell': missing)'. Stop.

I have tested your recommendations and it also fails with the same Error.

Thanks.

Comment: The hash (`#`) in make denotes the start of a comment.  The `#define` and all that follows, is being treated as a comment, hence the unterminated expression.  I'll update the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the pipe.  The reason it is not working is because you have defined it as a dynamic macro.  By using '=' it will re-evaluate the macro on each reference.  You have essentially created a recursive macro by trying to overload the `VERSION` variable as both the version and the filename.  Try using different variable names and make it static:

```
VERSION_NUMBER:=$(shell grep -w -m 1 "V1" server.h | sed $(VERSION) 's/#define V1[\t]//')

$(error VERSION_NUMBER=$(VERSION_NUMBER))
```

Remove the $(error) once you have it working.  Also, awk might be more efficient in this case anyway:

```
VERSION_NUMBER:=$(shell awk '/\<V1\>/ { print gensub(/^\#define V1[[:space:]]+/, "", ""); exit }' $(VERSION))
```

You also have the problem of the hash (pound for you US fellas) `#`.  It is terminating the expression as a comment.  Try this:

```
VERSION:=$(shell grep -w -m 1 "V2" server.h | sed 's/\#define V2[\t]//')
```

Or this:

```
VERSION:=$(shell awk '/\<V1\>/ { print gensub(/^\#define V1[[:space:]]+/, "", ""); exit }' server.h)
```

You will have this problem with many characters in make.  The Dollar being the most problematic to escape.  I have seen expressions like this:

```
V:=$(foreach f,$(list),$(eval $(shell create_rule $$$$(f))))
```

Sometimes it is better to write a shell script and call that:

*script.sh:*

```
#!/bin/sh

awk '/\<V1\>/ { print gensub(/^#define V1[[:space:]]+/, "", ""); exit }' "$@"
```

*Makefile:*

```
VERSION=$(shell script.sh server.h)
```